# Erro JS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Estou montando a função para abrir um menu. Mas estou recebendo a mensagem de erro "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Abaixo tem o código que estou usando para abrir o menu com JS

```js
   var veri = 1;
var trigger = document.getElementById('menu-trigger').addEventListener("click",function(){
var menu = document.getElementById('menu-hidde');
if (veri == 1) {
    menu.style.left = "0px";
    veri = 0;
}else{
    menu.style.left = "-100%";
    veri = 1;
}
})
```

E também o código em HTML onde cito o mesmo

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang"en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Styles Conference</title>
</head>



<body>
<div class="menu-trigger" id="menu-trigger">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<nav class="menu-hidde" id="menu-hidde">
 <ul>
  <li>teste</li>
  <li>teste</li>
  <li>teste</li>
  <li>teste</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: Olha, não sei se o seu problema é aqui no snippet ou numa app real, mas aqui no snippet que postou, são dois snippets distintos. Ou seja, o js não encontra o id que mandou pq eles não estão no mesmo contexto...

Comment: @DiegoSantos Eu estou aprendendo e achei os códigos em um snippet na internet. La funciona perfeitamente mas quando escrevi ele no Note Pad ++ apresentou esse erro.

Comment: Bom, testando em um só snippet aqui funcionou comigo. Mostre todo o fonte o seu arquivo... Outro detalhe, você chamou o js antes do html ou depois? Dê preferência a chamar depois ou declare ele no header...

Comment: Se for o caso, use o evento load do window.

Comment: @DiegoSantos atualizei meu post mostrando meu html por completo, aqui está o link onde estou tirando a referencia do código https://preloadweb.wordpress.com/2016/03/09/menu-retratil-com-css-e-javascript/

Comment: Seu script é o teste.js correto? Substitua por isso e fala o que acontece: '<script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js" async></script>'

Comment: @DiegoSantos Funcionou!! Muito obrigada, onde foi meu erro?

Comment: Vou responder... Se puder marcar como resposta, agradeço

Comment: @dotSonic Não, `ascyn` não carrega depois como o Diego afirmou, ele esta enganado ... o Async carrega *"assincronamente"*, ou seja não tem ordem, pode ser que funcione e pode ter ocasião que falhe, o correto é a se usar é `defer` ou `window.onload` ou `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, veja que coloquei uma vírgula "Neste caso" em minha resposta. Isto justifica a minha explicação.

Comment: Diego acho que esta errado (o downvote **não** é meu) Async não é por ultimo, nem neste caso nem em nenhum, async é assincrono, carrega sem ordem definida, como eu expliquei na minha resposta, se o HTML for grande você poderá ter problemas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289479/3635 - sua resposta funcionou no caso do AP por coincidência apenas, em outros ambientes ou variações de velocidade de download ou pequenos delays em servidores web, ascyn pode com certeza falhar.

Comment: Concordo @GuilhermeNascimento. De fato o async carrega de forma assincrona. Mas como eu disse nessa resposta, exclusiva a este problema, ele carrega por último. Justamente por ser assíncrono. E não tem problema quanto ao downvote. Assim como você estou aqui para somar a comunidade. A pontuação é importante para nos dar privilégio. Por isso pedi nesse caso. Mas isso faz parte :D

Comment: Não Diego, não carrega por ultimo, variações na rede e/ou servidor vão com certeza causar efeitos colaterais, não tem ordem não vai carregar exatamente por ultimo, só carrega por ultimo porque provavelmente ele ainda esta testando em localhost, no momento que for pra produção (site real) e alguém abrir em um 3G com algum oscilação vai provavelmente desencadear a falha *Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No import do seu script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
```

**Troque para:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js" async></script>
```

> **Motivo:**

O seu js está executando antes mesmo de o HTML carregar no navegador. Desta forma, ele não encontra o elemento que você está procurando com o `getElementById`.

Pense só: Como ele poderia adicionar o listener num objeto nulo?

O atributo `async`, faz com que o navegador carregue o seu script, neste caso, por último. Depois do HTML.

Comment: "O atributo async, faz com que o navegador carregue o seu script, neste caso, por último" - essa afirmação não é correta e não corresponde ao que o attributo `async` faz. Confirme você mesmo na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Como eu disse @Isac , existe uma vírgula "Neste Caso"

Comment: A virgula não muda a afirmação. O script pode não ser carregado em ultimo, dependendo de como o carregamento é processado. É improvável para um exemplo pequeno como o da pergunta, mas possível.

Comment: Olha, não acho produtivo ficarmos discutindo o português correto e nem a importância da vírgula em qualquer frase. Mas se a questão é técnica, vamos lá: A referencia está dentro da header. Quando o navegador recebe a resposta, recebe o js, com a tag async, ele deixa para executar o js depois do carregamento do DOM. Prova disso? O funcionamento deste script. Veja por si só. NESTE CASO, o async está executando o js depois do carregamento do DOM, que neste caso, utilizei a palavra HTML para me expressar...

Comment: Isac está certo no que disse. Na verdade, Async, como o próprio nome diz, carrega assincronicamente, pelo que bem me lembro, ele não é para scripts internos, mas sim, para scripts externos, além disso, ele não espera a analise de todos os elementos, como seria o caso da tag IMG, certamente você queria falar do Defer, esse sim, faz o que você falou.

Answer (score 4):

Tem que usar ou `window.onload` ou `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded');`, pois o script carregou antes da página e portanto os elementos HTML ainda não existiam.

Assim por exemplo:

```
document.addEvent('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var veri = 1;
    var trigger = document.getElementById('menu-trigger').addEventListener("click",function(){
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu-hidde');
    if (veri == 1) {
        menu.style.left = "0px";
        veri = 0;
    }else{
        menu.style.left = "-100%";
        veri = 1;
    }
    });
});
```

Ou pode usar o atributo `defer` nele também, assim:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
```

Semelhante ao que você fez em:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Que conforme o [**caniuse**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) é suportado por todos navegadores modernos, `defer` irá só executar o script quando o documento (DOM) estiver pronto.

### Async é diferente de Defer

O atributo async sugerido na resposta do Diego não funciona como é afirmado:

> O atributo async, faz com que o navegador carregue o seu script, neste caso, por último. Depois do HTML.

O `async` carrega o arquivo de maneira assíncrona, ou seja sem sincronia, ele pode terminar de carregar ou executar antes do HTML, dependendo do peso da página HTML, ou seja isto pode falhar.

O correto seria usar `defer` que este sim vai esperar o conteúdo HTML ser baixado e o "parse" ser feito e então sim o script executa.